# First chance vs second chance during fuzzing in windbg

Tags: windows, fuzzing

I tried to ask google and search here or at stackoverflow, but could not find the results I was looking for. Sorry if the question is a duplicate (please provide a link or hint to google it; thank you):

When I'm fuzzing some app.exe on Windows, should I try to investigate the crash when I find 'first chance' or 'second chance' in Windbg output?

For example:

> (cbc.fc8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
>   First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
>   This exception may be expected and handled.
>   eax=01f11218 ebx=00560000 ecx=803a3a3a edx=803a3a3a esi=01f11210 edi=01f72000
>   eip=7c911980 esp=0227c828 ebp=0227c834 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
>   cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010246
>   ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+0x32b:
>   7c911980 8b09            mov     ecx,dword ptr [ecx] 
>    ds:0023:803a3a3a=????????

Comment: doesn't this article answer your question: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-risk-detection/concepts/first-chance-exception ?

Comment: Thank you very much! Some how - probably "yes for 100%" but (as a n00b ;)) I need to ask: so I should definitely check more 'second chance' exceptions in the debuger's output. yes?

Comment: during fuzzing first chance exceptions may be valuable, especially if the app (or the framework it was built with) tries to handle all exceptions.